# JMenuItem accelerator not working when menu bar is hidden

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jmenubar

This question is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093773/jmenubar-selectionmodel-changelistener-only-fires-once).

I have a `JMenuBar` whose behavior is like the menu bars in Firefox and iTunes. That is, the menu bar is initially hidden, but when you press `Alt`, the menu bar appears.

The answer to the other question solved the problem of achieving that functionality, but it brought about *another* issue: The `JMenuItem` accelerators are not working when the `JMenuBar` is not visible. In other words, you must press `Alt` before `CTRL+F` (the installed accelerator) will work.

This is not supposed to be the case, though, because the `setAccelerator()` method states the following:

> public void setAccelerator(KeyStroke keyStroke)
>
> Sets the key combination which invokes the menu item's action listeners without navigating the menu hierarchy. It is the UI's responsibility to install the correct action. ***Note that when the keyboard accelerator is typed, it will work whether or not the menu is currently displayed.***

So, I'm wondering if this is another Java bug?

[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (to get the menu to appear, you press `Alt`, and the installed accelerator is `CTRL+F` for "Find" which brings up a dummy `JOptionPane` for input):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.MenuElement;
import javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class MenuBarTest extends JFrame {

    public MenuBarTest() {
        JMenu jMenu1 = new JMenu();
        JMenu jMenu2 = new JMenu();
        final JMenuBar jMenuBar1 = new JMenuBar();
        JMenuItem jMenuItem1 = new JMenuItem();
        JMenuItem jMenuItem2 = new JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jMenu1.setText("File");
        jMenuItem1.setText("jMenuItem1");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);
        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuItem2.setText("Find");
        jMenu2.add(jMenuItem2);
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);
        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        jMenuBar1.setVisible(false);
        ChangeListener listener = new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                MenuElement[] elements = MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager().getSelectedPath();
                jMenuBar1.setVisible(elements.length > 0 && elements[0] == jMenuBar1);
            }
        };
        MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager().addChangeListener(listener);

        jMenuItem2.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        jMenuItem2.setText("Find");
        jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                String what = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(MenuBarTest.this, "Search for what?");
                System.out.println(what);
            }
        });

        pack();
        setSize(500,500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MenuBarTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: my take is that it's a documentation issue: the "displayed" here means addresses the normal state that a menu/item under a menuBar is hidden (because we see only the menubar). Nevertheless, it is _showing_ (because it's visible and all of its ancestors are showing), thus allowing bindings to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read your emphasis carefully

> Note that when the keyboard accelerator is typed, it will work whether or not the menu is currently displayed.

This talks about the *menu* not its parent. Meaning that the *menu* might be currently not displayed. Nevertheless, the real (probably not overly well documented) desisive property is that it must be *showing*. Had updated my answer to your previous question.

Comment: Wow. Like the last question I would've never thought of that on my own. This community is filled with truly gifted developers!

Comment: Oh how I love Java... So, I extended `JMenuBar` and (ok, don't throw tomatoes at me) tried to import the new class into Netbeans (yes, the GUI builder), and I ran into this fun little detail: not all of `JMenuBar`'s methods have been completed. Someone complained about this in (get this) 1999: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4087846 and it STILL has not been fixed. A blog article, aptly titled, "wtf" has been created in this bug's honor.. in, oh, 2006. http://tsareto.blogspot.com/2006/05/wtf.html. So, don't call `JMenuBar.getHelpMenu()`, because Java hasn't gotten to it yet.

Comment: SSCCE: 
    `public static void main(String[] args) {
        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        bar.getHelpMenu();
    }`

Comment: `@Override
    public JMenu getHelpMenu() {
        return null;
    }` did the trick lol